# How to set up a flask API to return data from a python function to a flask route

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am trying to display some data that is out from a python function in a file called poemBot.py and to display that output in a webpage using a simple flask app. Here is a link to the github repo: https://github.com/nditanaka/flask_poembot_app My routes are set up as follows:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from poemBot import tap

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return tap()


@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    return {'time': time.time()}


@app.route('/api/about')
def about():
    return 'This is the about page'


@app.route('/api/poem')
def get_random_poem():
    return tap()
```

My poemBot file from which the **tap()** function is called looks like as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# main.py
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import time
import socket
import csv
import textwrap
import random


def printPoem():
    # get a random poem
    randPoem = random.choice(allPoems)
    # nicely wrap the content for the printer
    # Title and Author are printed in 'M' medium font, limit is 32 character per line
    # poem is printed in 'S' small font, limit is 32 characters per line
    # book and publisher are in "fontB", limit is 42 character per line
    wrappedTitle = textwrap.fill(randPoem[1], width=32)
    wrappedAuthor = textwrap.fill(randPoem[2], width=32)
    wrappedPoem = ""
    for line in randPoem[3].splitlines():
        wrappedLine = textwrap.fill(line, width=32, subsequent_indent="    ")
        wrappedPoem += wrappedLine + "\n"
    # print the poem
    # return (wrappedTitle, '\n', wrappedPoem, '\n',
        # wrappedAuthor, '\n', randPoem[4], '\n', randPoem[0])
    years = str(randPoem[4])
    author = str(wrappedTitle)
    poem = wrappedAuthor
    url = str(randPoem[3])

    return {author, poem, years, url}
# Print random poem, called on tap


def tap():
    # print a random poem
    return printPoem()


def hold():
    return ('Goodbye!')


# Load up all poems from CSV
# poem CSV is structured with the columns: number,title,author,poem,book
# goldenTreasuryPoems.csv was parsed from the text of Project Gutenberg EBook #19221
# http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19221
# the poem column contains the full text of the poem with no markup, only \n
# the CSV is in PC437 encoding since the printer only supports this character set
with open('poembot_poems_2020.csv') as csvPoems:
    allPoems = list(csv.reader(csvPoems, delimiter=','))

# Start printing
print('Hello!')
print('Ready to print')
tap()
```

The poemBot.py file works by reading csv file whose contents are then output by the **printPoem()** function. I have a suspicion that my **printPoem()** is returning the wrong kind of object, or the way I am calling the **tap()** in the routes in main.py is wrong.

When I run my flask app with flask run, the error I get is

> "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Edit: modified the files and the error now is:

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response tuple. The tuple must have the form (body, status, headers), (body, status), or (body, headers).

Comment: You need to have a return in your API route function. For example, `return tap()`. Also your `tap()` function needs to return the thing you want to send through response rather than print them.

Comment: I've updated my functions to return the object I want thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to change in your code: 
1 ) When you create a route function, it has to return a Render_template object or a string.
It should look like this:

```
@app.route('/api/poem')
def get_random_poem():
    return tap() 
    # tap() as to be a string
```

2 ) If you know a file will be imported you should use the "**name**" variable:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    print('Hello!')
    print('Ready to print')
    tap()
```

3 ) When you return values with commas "," it transforms the type to a tuple. If you want it to be a string you have to use the operand "+"

```
return "line1" + "\n" + "line2...
```

Hope it helped you!